# Usage of file protocol in HTTP request

Tags: jmeter, file-read

Reading file using [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) is suggested for [Passing variables between threads](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/hints_and_tips.html#variable_and_threads).

> For example you could use the Save Responses to a file listener or perhaps a BeanShell PostProcessor in one thread, and read the file using the HTTP Sampler "file:" protocol, and extract the information using a PostProcessor

Which is working, but should the warning in doc be ignored?

> Note: the FILE protocol is intended for testing purposes only. It is handled by the same code regardless of which HTTP Sampler is used.

Is/when it safe/good practice to use file protocol or is it deprecated/bad practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Using Beanshell PostProcessor is a definitely bad practice, [since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) and [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/) language
2. Writing and reading files might cause massive [disk IO](https://scoutapm.com/blog/understanding-disk-i-o-when-should-you-be-worried) overhead which can become the bottleneck for your script especially when it comes to high loads. Moreover in-memory operations will be much faster than writing/reading the file to/from the file system

Assuming all above:

although there is nothing wrong with using `file` protocol if you need to read the data from a file on the file system, it's better to avoid these interim files and pass the data between threads using memory, the options are in:

1. Use [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) in 1st thread group to store the value and [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) in other Thread Groups to read the previously stored value
2. Use [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter/) which can be used for passing variables between threads, even if they live in different Thread Groups (see [SynchronizationExample.jmx](https://jmeter-plugins.org/img/examples/SynchronizationPluginsExample.jmx) for a practical use case). Inter-Thread Communication Plugin can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)